# Multithreaded processing from Java queue(s)

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

Consider an application which uses an in-memory FIFO `Java` queue to deposit objects that will be subsequently processed by a thread, executing in parallel with many other threads (e.g., as part of a `ThreadPool`).

Each object must be processed by a "compatible" thread and that compatibility is assured via checking a label associated with the object (i.e., each thread can process certain types of objects, not all of them). If a thread reads an object from the queue and the label it reads is not among the ones it supports, it has to ignore the object.

Some additional characteristics the application has to fulfill:

1. In-order processing (i.e., all objects with the same label should be processed in the order they are deposited in the queue).
2. High performance (i.e., capable of processing thousands of rather "heavy" objects per second).

One could use the [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html), as suggested in an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614752/which-is-queue-in-multithread-java-without-blocking), but a single queue makes things tricky for segregating the input per label. Alternatively, each thread could be assigned with handling a single label, so it could have its own non-concurrent queue. Or maybe another approach should be followed.

What would be the best way to implement the above specification?

Comment: A few ways I think you could approach: 1) have a concurrent queue per label 2) have an intermediate sorting consumer 3) use [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) for messaging as this sounds like a publish/subscribe sort of problem.

Comment: It is a publish/subscribe problem, but I want to use only "simple" in-memory queues, for performance reasons. A concurrent queue per label is probably the best solution. Thanks and +1. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a thread reads an object from the queue and the label it reads is not among the ones it supports, it has to ignore the object.

Does that mean that some of the tasks that go into the queue will never be performed?  And does it mean that there's no way to predict which ones will be ignored and which ones will be processed?

That doesn't sound like a very good design.

If that's not what you meant, then maybe "ignored" was not the right word.

> Each object must be processed by a "compatible" thread ... all objects with the same label should be processed in the order they are deposited in the queue

I'm not going to try to guess what could be different about the different kinds of worker threads, but If I was given that requirement, I would have a different thread pool for each different kind of worker.  Then it becomes the responsibility of whoever generates the tasks to put them in the right queue.

Comment: It will probably need to be one thread per object category, because there has to be in-order processing for the objects that belong to the same category. Thanks and +1. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why would a thread *reject* a task based upon the object's label?

The thread that picks up the task from the queue must act like a worker thread. You must design/write in a manner, that the thread picks up the object (or task) from the queue, reads its label, and processes it based on its label.

You must not have a any correspondence between a *object type* and a *thread type*. Each thread should be written to handle any object.

Comment: Every thread will do specialized processing, which is related to the "category" of each object, represented by its label. No thread can process all categories of objects and the idea is to reuse the processing logic in each thread, instead of having to re-instantiate it every time. Other than that, the worker model is of course applicable.

Comment: My question is still on the need of a thread type for each category. The specialised processing logic must be in Executable task objects, which can be called/executed from any thread. To save reinstantiation, think of using a Singleton pattern of such objects. If the processing is stateful, and requires you to save state in fields, think about using pools of such specialised task executor objects.

Comment: You cannot guarantee in-order processing of objects from each category, if you have more than 1 threads processing them. +1 for the discussion. :-)

Comment: @PNS, but why have different kinds of Thread?  Why not instead, have different kinds of _task_ objects that can be run by generic worker threads?

Comment: Because there are millions of such task objects, categorized in a few dozen categories.

Comment: @PNS Are you saying that you would have a "single" worker thread, per category, so that you ensure "in-order-processing"? And you want to start execution of next item (of that category) only after completing the execution of an item that was received before?

Comment: Yes. Every thread processes the objects of its category and there is one thread per category. The objects arrive in the queue interleaved.

Comment: @PNS if you are going to have one thread per category, then it would make a lot of sense to also have one queue per category.  That would greatly simplify how the worker threads take their tasks off the queue, and it doesn't sound like it would be a huge burden on whatever thread(s) put tasks on the queues.